# Can these two indefinite integrals be evaluated in closed form?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I'm wondering whether any of these two indefinite integrals

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\alpha \sinh(x)^{-4/3}}}dx$$
$$\int \frac{\sinh(x)^{-4/3}}{\sqrt{1+\alpha\sinh(x)^{-4/3}}}dx$$

can be evaluated in closed form. I've tried a couple of substitutions, looked at integral tables, and asked Mathematica, to no avail so far.

Comment: what do we know about alpha?

Comment: No constraints, $\alpha$ can be any real number.

Comment: i think this will help you   http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.bams/1183531821

Comment: I doubt reading Risch's original work is helpful to the OP.

Comment: how would you prove that?

Comment: substitution $x=arcsinh(y)$ brings the integral to a form which looks like it could be solved by elliptic integrals.

Comment: Thanks. That brings them into slightly nicer looking form. For example, with further substitution $y=z^4$, the second integral becomes $\int \frac{z^2}{\sqrt{(z^6+1)(z^4+\alpha)}}dz$. However for Elliptic integrals I need a polynomial of degree at most 4 in the square root if I'm not mistaken.